# Using Javascript's Hash-Table's value to call a function

Tags: javascript, function, hashtable, key-value

I basically want to below code to work, is there a way ?

```
var hash_table = new Object();
hash_table['a'] = foo;
alert(hash_table['a'](1)); // 1 is just a simple parameter for example.
                           // this line should print "2" in alert();.


function foo(params) {
    alert("params: " + params); // just simple print in alert(); (will print 1)
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? I have the expected behaviour: two alerts, the first with "params: 1" and the second with "2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `foo` after using it. Make sure you define `foo` first then use it.

So,

```
function foo(params) {
    ...
}
```

Should come before

```
hash_table['a'] = foo;
```

Comment: The Miko Diko code should be working as well, because the function declaration is [hoisted](http://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-hoisting/) to the top of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with that code. The code does what you describe it should do.